# Unable to Set HREF on React Router Link Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Trying to add a  to an existing React component but running into some difficulties. Given the following code

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

require('./NavBar.scss');

class NavBar extends React.Component {

  authButton() {
    console.log(Link)
    const route = this.props.currentUser ? 'logout' : 'login';
    return <Link to={ `/${route}` }>route</Link>
  }
```

The navbar component fails to render and I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (react-router-dom.js:198)
```

If I change the "to" prop to a function like this

```
return <Link to={ () => return `/${route}` }>route</Link>
```

the component does actually render but I get this message "checkPropTypes.js:19 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `to` supplied to `Link`."

Any idea on what could be causing this. Have used this component on the same version of react-router-dom (5.0.0) on other projects without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it with `withRoute` from react-router-dom. In the bottom of the file, export default navbar, write this line

`export default withRoute(navbar)`

Don't forget import it from react-router-dom.

There's usually a problem with react-router-dom when the component isn't included in `Route` element in the 'main component' such App.js.

`<Route path='/' component={}`

Something like that.

I'm assuming this since a lot of people get this problem with React-router-dom.